# Android Studio Project content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

i've been working in android studio for many years before, and im facing this new issue, im working with android studio in mac, but then i copy the project and open it in windows, and its says like this :

[image]

is anybody can help me with this issue?, i've been facing this issue about 2 days and find no luck, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

1).Close android studio.

2).Delete all the contents of below directories.

```
          C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\build-cache
          C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\cache
          C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\caches
```

3)Start Android Studio.